# Play 2.0.1 - Scala templates string concatting + re-usable code block

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

While just a little issue, based on the doc, I should be able to create a re-usable block.  It could be my lack of Scala experience juicing me here...

I have a List of Strings that get passed to the `.scala.html` file. The strings are javascript file references without the ".js".

```
@jsFileWithExtension(file: String) = @{
  val newFile = file + ".js
}
@for(jsFile <- headJs) {
   <script src="/assets/javascripts/@jsFileWithExtension("@jsFile")"></script>
}
```

It's currently loading the jsFile without the extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@jsFileWithExtension(file: String) = @{ file + ".js" }


@for(jsFile <- headJs) {
   <script src="/assets/javascripts/@jsFileWithExtension(jsFile)"></script>
}
```

Your `jsFileWithExtension` needs to return a value. Right now it returns `Unit`. Then as Daniel pointed out the parameter to the function does not need the quote or magic `@` char.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply append a .js ?

```
@for(jsFile <- headJs) {
   <script src="/assets/javascripts/@(jsFile).js"></script>
}
```

Comment: Key here is the enclosing in () as otherwise .js looks like a method call to play

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work instead:

```
@jsFileWithExtension(jsFile)
```

As in, without quotes and `@` for `jsFileWithExtension` parameter, given this is already Scala code?

Comment: No, it doesn't (at least not for me!) I probably should have pointed out the methods I tried :)